# Replacing values with weight in a table

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have a table that holds the value of my assets and one column with the total value. I was wondering if there is a way to replace each of the absolute value with the weight

```
Apple Google FB MSFT Total
2       3    1    0    6
1       2    4    1    8
...
```

and I want to change it to

```
Apple Google   FB     MSFT   Total
0.33    0.5    0.166    0      6
0.125   0.25    0.5    0.125   8
...
```

Are there any elegant ways to do this with python?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just divide all values by the corresponding value in the Total column.

```
df.iloc[:, :-1] = df.iloc[:, :-1].div(df['Total'], 0)
```

edit: and think about what you want if the total is zero.